# logout of site through Facebook with Rails and Koala

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, logout, koala

I'm using the Facebook login with Koala for my RoR web application.
I'm using Clearance authentication, and when user logs in with Facebook I'm recognizing the site existing user or subscribing a new user.

I am having an issue with logging out:
I'm trying to logout of the site without logging out of Facebook.
As I understood from the FB API, I should use the url for logging out:

```
"https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=#{sign_in_url}&access_token=#{access_token}".
```

When directing to that URL it seems like cookies changed, but then on the sign_in page when getting to the parse facebook cookies part (for checking if user logged in to facebook), the

```
oauth.get_user_from_cookies(cookies)
```

returns:

```
OAuthException: Code was invalid or expired. The session is invalid because the user logged out
```

Like it deletes the whole session instead of just change the cookies...?
* I checked and the cookie fbsr_... still exists! shoudln't it be changed to fbs_...?!

I would appreciate help on this.
Thanks a lot!
Moozly.

Comment: No answers...? :-(. Please help...